# CardView onClickListener to go to another intent

Tags: java, android-studio-3.5

I'm trying to write code code such that when clicked on any cardview, it moves to another activity screen. Here is my code for the xml and java part. When the app is running, the cardview can be displayed but, the new activity is not opening.

This the code for XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/homepage"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1">

    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/mypet"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/petlogo100"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="My Pet"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Information about your Pet"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/health"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/pethealth"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Track Health"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Follow the health of your Pet"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/vetVisit"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/vetvisit2"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Visit Vet"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Details about the medical schedule"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/overall"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/overall_health"
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Track Health"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Follow the health of your Pet"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This the code for JAVA.
    package com.example.healthypet;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private CardView petCard, healthCard,vetCard,overallCard;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        petCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.mypet);
        healthCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.health);
        vetCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.vetVisit);
        overallCard = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.overall);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i;

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.mypet:

                i= new Intent(this,MyPetPage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.health:

                i= new Intent(this,PetHealth.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.vetVisit:

                i= new Intent(this,VetPage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.overall:

                i= new Intent(this,overall.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

                default:break;

        }

    }

}
```